# I cannot understand why my condition is failing and unable break an infinite for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and tried editing and running following code in about:blank on Chrome and the output I get is an infinite loop-

```js
    // Draw as many smileys as you want! 
    var drawSmileys = function (howManyTimes) {
      for (var i = 0; i < howManyTimes < 20; i++) { 
        console.log(i + " ;p");  
      } 
    }; 
    drawSmileys(15);
```

Can some one tell me why the condition is not failing?

Comment: `i < howManyTimes < 20` is not valid.

Comment: It's valid but not doing what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

Your looping condition syntax is not producing the logic that you want it to.

It appears that you want to continue looping as long as your loop counter (`i`) is both less than `howManyTimes` and `20`. Because of that, you'll need to use the short-circuited AND operator (`&&`) because that's 2 conditions that both need to be true for the loop to continue.

```js
// Draw as many smileys as you want! 
var drawSmileys = function (howManyTimes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < howManyTimes && howManyTimes < 20; i++) { 
    console.log(i + " ;p");  
  } 
}; 
drawSmileys(20); // Doesn't run
drawSmileys(19); // Does run
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be another approach

```
// Draw as many smileys as you want! 
var drawSmileys = function (howManyTimes) {
  howManyTimes = howManyTimes > 20 ? 20 : howManyTimes;
  for (var i = 0; i < howManyTimes; i++) { 
    console.log(i + " ;p");  
  } 
}; 
drawSmileys(21);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is infinite because it's always true:

```js
console.log(0 < 15 < 20)//true
console.log(1 < 15 < 20)//true
console.log(5 < 15 < 20)//true
console.log(15 < 15 < 20)//true
```

The evaluation is `(0<15) < 1` is `(true) < 1` and this is false because `(0<15) == 1` is `true` then `1<1` is false

```js
console.log((0 < 15))//true
console.log((0 < 15) < 20)//true
console.log((0 < 15)==1)//true
console.log((0 < 15)<1)//false
```

Then, the only way to obtain a false  with this `x<y<z` is if `z == 1` and `x<y == true` that is `(true)<1`

If you want to put two limits you could do:

```js
var drawSmileys = function (howManyTimes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < howManyTimes && i < 20; i++) { 
    console.log(i + " ;p");  
  } 
}; 
console.log(drawSmileys(8))//7 smiles
console.log("----")
console.log(drawSmileys(200))//19 smiles
```

Comment: Does the condition '1<15<20' work as '1<15' OR '15<20' rather than '1<15 AND 15<20' ?

Comment: I got the condition statement now. It is working as below- 

(21<15)<20
//since first part is false we get 0. So it now becomes
0<20 // This is true. 

Hence i never break the loop.

Comment: exactly! (21<15) is false, then 0<20 is true